# Can Android still read a QR Code on a card if it's laminated?

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, zxing

Can Android's ZXing library still read a QR Code on a card if it's laminated?

Comment: This sounds like from a Zen generator.... Do you want to know whether you will be able to read a QR Code if the item to read the code from is laminated? If so, the answer is that it doesn't have to do with Android or the library you use, but with the quality of the camera and the quality of the item you read from. Usually I'd say this is no problem.

Comment: also depends on the lighting in the room you're scanning the QR code in. You could have a 10mp camera on a top end HTC/Samsung, but if you have light shining straight down on the laminate you're going to have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Android apps (and its libraries) use the camera to read QR-codes as (as far as I'm aware ;)) the phones don't come with infrared scanners. The library should be able to read the card, as long as there's not a beam of light blocking the camera from getting a clear shot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the camera will still be able to scan and read the QR-code but you shouldn't laminate your Android device.